# VBScript - Error 0x80041017 (null)

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

**As Cheran S stated below, it's a good idea to avoid using "taskmgr" for this script.  I'm not going to edit the code, as I feel it's best to maintain the original question as much as possible since doing so would partially invalidate & obfuscate Cheran's answer & comment.**

**A good alternative to "taskmgr" would be "CharMap" (for simple & fast testing).**

---

Running Windows XP Professional (32-bit) and I've got this script that's throwing up this error:

```
Script:   C:\test.vbs
Line:     40
Char:     3
Error:    0x80041017
Code:     80041017
Source:   (null)
```

Here's the code:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objWshNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objWshNet.ComputerName

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Dim arrWinTitle(2)
    arrWinTitle(0) = "My Documents"
    arrWinTitle(1) = "Control Panel"

Dim arrProcName(3)
    arrProcName(0) = "'taskmgr.exe'"
    arrProcName(1) = "'calc.exe'"
    arrProcName(2) = "'notepad.exe'"

Sub srBlockWindow(strWinTitle, intWinTitle, strProcName, intProcName)
    i = 0
    Do While i = 0
        If objWshShell.AppActivate(strWinTitle(intWinTitle)) Then
            objWshShell.AppActivate(strWinTitle(intWinTitle))
            Wscript.Sleep 100
            objWshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
            Wscript.Sleep 100
        End If

        If intWinTitle = 0 Then
            intWinTitle = intWinTitle + 1
        Else
            intWinTitle = 0
        End If

        Wscript.Sleep 100

        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE NAME = " & strProcName(intProcName))

        For Each objProcess In colProcesses
            objProcess.Terminate()
        Next

        If intProcName >= 0 Then
            intProcName = intProcName + 1
        ElseIf intProcName >= 5 Then
            intProcName = 0
        End If

        Set colProcesses = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub

Call srBlockWindow(arrWinTitle, 0, arrProcName, 0)
```

I've reviewed [this](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-server-scripting/11494/process-kill-script), but I believe my script doesn't have any issues with the quotes.  For the sake of clarity, I'm getting the error at the start of the "For Each ..." string.

What's peculiar is that it will run fine the first time, but once it loops, that's when I get the error.  So, it will close all the desired Windows/Applications, but once it goes through it's second iteration, I get the error.  I've inserted "On Error Resume Next", but that doesn't resolve it (I will add it later, since it's required to resolve the conflict when the Window/Process Starts simultaneously with Close/End/Stop attempts made by the Script).

**I think it's because I should be conditionally checking if the process exists; problem is, I'm not quite sure how to do that with this code (I've never been good with Collections).  Anybody have suggestions on how to do it with this code specifically?**

---

I reviewed [this](http://www.techimo.com/forum/applications-operating-systems/117464-need-vbulletin-script-check-see-if-process-running.html) and tried to write a quick alternative script, but it didn't really work.  Here's the code:

```
Set service = GetObject("winmgmts:")

Dim arrProcName(3)
    arrProcName(0) = "'taskmgr.exe'"
    arrProcName(1) = "'calc.exe'"
    arrProcName(2) = "'notepad.exe'"

Sub srTest(strProc, intProc)
    i = 0
    Do While i = 0
        For Each Process In Service.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
            If Process.Name = strProc(intProc) Then
                Process.Name.Terminate
                Process.Terminate
            End If
        Next

        If intProc = 0 Then
            intProc = intProc + 1
        ElseIf intProc >= 3 Then
            intProc = 0
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Call srTest(arrProcName, 0)
```

As you can see, I tried both "Process.Terminate" & "Process.Name.Terminate", but neither yielded anything (not even an error).  I further tested it with "Wscript.Echo Process.Name" & "Wscript.Echo strProc(intProc)", but neither of these worked too.

Now that I've failed at this alternative solution, I'm feeling that I'm wildly stabbing in the dark for solutions, so I'll defer these esoteric challenges to the community that is vastly superior to me.

---

There might be a few here who are reading this and wondering why I'm targeting My Documents, Control Panel, taskmgr.exe, calc.exe, & notepad.exe.  Almost everybody reading this will probably be able to extrapolate on their own, but I'll make sure I'm clear on this for those who need it.  I'm doing this because it makes it easier to test, since all of these can be accessed simply by using the "Run" shortcut (Windows Key + R) & then entering the following strings (one at a time, of course):

- My Documents
- Control
- taskmgr
- calc
- notepad

You likely knew the keywords, but I just wanted to highlight *why* I'm using these specific ones (speed & simplicity).

---

**I'll remove this if Cheran adds the final code to the answer posted**

Final Solution:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objWshNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objWshNet.ComputerName

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Dim arrWinTitle
    arrWinTitle = Array("My Documents", "Control Panel")

Dim arrProcName
    arrProcName = Array("'charmap.exe'", "'calc.exe'", "'notepad.exe'")

Sub srBlockWindow(strWinTitle, intWinTitle, strProcName, intProcName)
    i = 0
    Do While i = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            ' In the Event of Conflict w/Initiation of Window or Process
        If objWshShell.AppActivate(strWinTitle(intWinTitle)) Then
            objWshShell.AppActivate(strWinTitle(intWinTitle))
            Wscript.Sleep 100
            objWshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
            Wscript.Sleep 100
        End If

        intWinTitle = (intWinTitle + 1) Mod (UBound(strWinTitle) + 1)

        Wscript.Sleep 100

        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE NAME = " & strProcName(intProcName))

        For Each objProcess In colProcesses
            objProcess.Terminate()
        Next

        intProcName = (intProcName + 1) Mod (UBound(strProcName) + 1)

        Set colProcesses = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub

Call srBlockWindow(arrWinTitle, 0, arrProcName, 0)
```

Here's a quick script I threw together to test it against:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

i = 0
Do While i = 0
    objWshShell.Run "explorer.exe /e, C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents"
    Wscript.Sleep 200
    objWshShell.Run "CharMap.exe"
    Wscript.Sleep 200
    objWshShell.Run "Control.exe"
    Wscript.Sleep 200
    objWshShell.Run "calc.exe"
    Wscript.Sleep 200
    objWshShell.Run "notepad.exe"
    Wscript.Sleep 200
Loop
```

**BE CAREFUL!  Adjust the timings so that you can end "Wscript.exe" without too many problems.  Best to run both scripts simultaneously to see how it works.**

Comment: You might not want to use "taskmgr.exe" as a sample process name when your script is supposed to run in an infinite loop, especially when posting on a community site.  How do you stop the "wscript.exe" process?  (Of course, shame on me for just running code without inspecting it first...)

Comment: @Cheran S - LOL, sorry; I've got a fall back.  I never accounted for that issue b/c of two reasons: (1) I didn't have working code, rofl.  (2) I use this command in the Run Dialogue Box: `TaskKill /Im Wscript.exe /F`.  There's one caveat to that: I'm running XP Professional Clients, and the "TaskKill" Command only works on XP Pro.  The alternative, for XP Home is `TsKill Wscript`.  I believe this principle applies for all Home vs Pro editions (XP/Vista/7).  Once again, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two big issues I found:

1. The main problem here is in the way you define your arrays.  The number you specify in the array declaration is the largest array subscript.  Since VBScript arrays are always indexed starting at 0, you actually need to specify one less than the number of elements in the array.

   ```
   ' This is wrong:
   Dim arrWinTitle(2)
   Dim arrProcName(3)

   ' Should be:
   Dim arrWinTitle(1)
   Dim arrProcName(2)
   ```

   You could also use the [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxhtazh%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to initialize your array, assuming that you know beforehand how many elements are in it.  In that case, you would just declare `arrWinTitle` as a Variant and not as an array:

   ```
   Dim arrWinTitle
   arrWinTitle = Array("My Documents", "Control Panel")
   ```
2. If you make that change and try to run the script, you'll still get a "Subscript out of range" error.  That error is caused by this block:

   ```
   If intProcName >= 0 Then
       intProcName = intProcName + 1
   ElseIf intProcName >= 5 Then
       intProcName = 0
   End If
   ```

   First off, the maximum subscript should be 2 for `strProcName`, and not 5.  Even then, this code won't work.  It seems like what you're trying to do is loop through the elements of array, then start over back at 0.  A better of doing this is with the [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basszbdt%28VS.85%29.aspx) operator:

   ```
   intProcName = (intProcName + 1) Mod (UBound(strProcName) + 1)
   ```

   Notice also how I use the [`UBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to avoid hard-coding the actual length of the array.

---

I won't spend too much time analyzing your second example, since it was just an attempt to make the first example work.  I will note, however, that in your `arrProcName` array, the process names still have the single quotes around them, which is one reason why that script didn't work either.

Comment: Woops!  To your second point, I completely forgot to edit that ElseIf string to 2!  I was prototyping with a couple more items and removed a few from the 2nd Array, but I didn't clean the interacting code block.  Give me some time to digest your post, as your use of the Array function, the Mod operator & the UBound function are all new to me (thanks for remembering that I'm a complete neophyte & adding those resource links!).  After I test & figure out how the complete script should look like, I'll make sure to get you the "Check Mark".  You won't have to wait as long as last time, though =D.

Comment: Since I'm pretty dumb (actually, really dumb), it took me awhile to piece it together.  Just in case there's anybody who's as dumb as I am (which is pretty hard to accomplish, so I'll assume that it's probably an individual that is newer to VBS than I am) I've posted the final code to the question.  Unless, of course, you want to Copy & Paste it into your answer Cheran?  Unfortunately, I haven't really figured out exactly how UBound works (the very term "subscript" evades me); I'll eventually get it, but for now, I'm content with working code =D.  Thanks a bunch Cheran!