# Create Loop based on Length of User Input

Tags: vba, vbscript

**Problem**

Although the current code prompts the user to retry their input if he/she enters an input that is less or more than 8 characters on the first try, the user can still enter an erroneous code on the second try.

**Question**

How do I make a loop that keeps on prompting the user to retry, until their answer is 8 characters long?

Alternatively, is it possible to make an input that only has space for 8 characters?

**Current VBScript:**

```
Call InputChecker

Function InputChecker
  Dim Input
  Input = InputBox("Enter your name") 

  If Len(Input) <> 8 Then
    Msgbox ("Input must be 8 characters")
    Input = InputBox("Enter your name")
  Else
    MsgBox ("Input Success")
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109841/vbscript-data-validation-numeric-1-results-in-infinite-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no max length inputbox in VBS, but try this:

```
Dim UserInput
UserInput = InputChecker
' You can reuse the accepted user input

Function InputChecker
    Dim Input, Length       
    Do
        Input = Trim(InputBox("Enter your name")) ' Remove spaces at front and back
        Length = Len(Input)
        If Length <> 8 Then Msgbox "Input must be 8 characters"
    Loop Until Length = 8
    MsgBox "Input Success"
    InputChecker = Input
End Function
```

---

To trap <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or **<kbd>X</kbd>** the Inputbox, check if it's **FALSE**. See below with adjustments to UI and program flow.

```
Dim UserInput
UserInput = InputChecker
' You can reuse the accepted user input
If Length = 8 Then Wscript.Echo "User input: """ & UserInput & """"

Function InputChecker
    Dim Input, Length       
    Do
        Input = InputBox("Enter your name","Enter your name (must be 8 characters)")
        If Input = False Then Exit Do
        Input = Trim(Input) ' Remove spaces at front and back
        Length = Len(Input)
        If Length <> 8 Then
            If Msgbox("Input must be 8 characters, not " & Len(Input) & "!",5+48,"INPUT LENGTH ERROR") = 2 Then
                Input = "" ' Reset it to empty string
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until Length = 8
    InputChecker = Input
End Function
```

Ref: 
[MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx), 
[InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: thank you this works well! Is there a way to make the Loop end if the user clicks on the Exit or Cancel button?

Comment: Check second part of solution.